# Function to round digits

Tags: r

I have made this function to round digits in columns, but it does not work. Does anyone know why?

```
id <- rep(c(300,450), each=6)
visit <- rep(1:6,2)
trt <- rep(c(0,"A",0,"B",0,"C"),2)
q1 <- c(30.34,100.56,40.76,89.89,70.43, 75.68,35.34,106.12,30.89,85.98,65.75, 70.69)
q2 <- c(50.67,150.91,40.51,95.78,60.93, 90.12,55.78,120.84,60.17,99.63,59.27, 75.38)
df <- data.frame(id,visit,trt,q1,q2)
df
round <- function(i){
  df[,i] <- round(df[,i],1)
  df[,i]
}
round(4)



> round <- function(i){
+   df[,i] <- round(df[,i],1)
+   df[,i]
+ }
> round(4)
Error in round(df[, i], 1) : unused argument (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `round` calls, within itself, `round`. Except, now `round` only has 1 argument (`x`). What you've unintentionally done is created an recursive function. `round` will call itself, which will call itself, which will call itself...... until

> Error: C stack usage  15925248 is too close to the limit

In your case it never made it that far, due to it being stopped by an error.

What you *really* wanted to do was have your `round` call the original `round`, which can be found in the namespace `base`. So, instead of having R looking for `round` in its immediate namespace ("GlobalEnv", where your `round` is defined), we'll tell it to look a specific place:

```
round <- function(i){
  df[,i] <- base::round(df[,i],1)
  df[,i]
}
```

*Edit to add Ronak Shah's comment* because it's a very, very good point.

> Although I think it is better to name functions differently than already existing functions

I.e. avoid renaming built-in function names.

Answer (score 0):

You have named a user-defined function the same as a built-in function, namely `round`. As such, it will overwrite the built-in function.

This error

`Error in round(df[, i], 1) : unused argument (1)`

is kicked off because `round(df[,i],1)` tries to call your defined `round` function which has only one argument to pass to.

Comment: ahh didn't think about that, now I see it, thanks!:)